# ggplot2 in shiny error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class packageIQR

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am attempting to build a simple `shiny` app that creates a data table based on inputs and outputs a line plot using `ggplot2`. I receive the following error:

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class packageIQR

In this app, a user uses a slider to define the time period, or the length of X, and also the change in value by defining the starting value and the change in the value over X. The plot is a linear line. I am new to `shiny`, so if there are better ways to set up this I also would like suggestions on the best way to set up the server code, but for now I simply get an error and produce no plot.

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output){

  reactive({
    data <- data.table(months = seq(1, input$months, by = 1),
                   value  = seq(input$startingValue, 
                               input$startingValue + input$valueChange, 
                               length.out = input$months))
  })


   output$yield <- renderPlot({  
     p <- ggplot(data(), aes(x=months, y=value, colour=value)) +geom_line()
     print(p)
   })
})
```

Comment: `data` is not `callable`.  Try without the `()`: `p <- ggplot(data, aes(...`

Comment: If I remove the () I get a new error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class function

Comment: `data` is a function in R.  You should generally avoid using it as a variable name...

Comment: Thanks that is useful. I changed it to inputData and now see object 'inputData' not found

Comment: More specifically: Error in ggplot(inputData, aes(x = months, y = yield, colour = yield)) : 
  object 'inputData' not found

Comment: I'm not super familiar with `shiny`, but I think you want to assign the result of `reactive`:  `inputData <- reactive({...})` then call it in the ggplot section:  `ggplot(inputData(), ...)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to define  the reactive function :

```
data <- reactive({
        data.table(months = seq(1, input$months, by = 1),
               value  = seq(input$startingValue, 
                           input$startingValue + input$valueChange, 
                           length.out = input$months))
})
```

Note here you don't need to define the reactive function since you have one caller. You can put all the code in the plot section:

```
output$yield <- renderPlot({  
 data <- data.table(months = seq(1, input$months, by = 1),
               value  = seq(input$startingValue, 
                           input$startingValue + input$valueChange, 
                           length.out = input$months))
 p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=months, y=value, colour=value)) +geom_line()
 print(p)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The second part of your answer was a working solution and very clear.

Comment: Perhaps I am doing it wrong... but when I include the first piece of code outside of output$yield but within shinyServer and then keep the rest of output$yield the same [including p <- ... and print(p)] I get an error "ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class reactive"

Comment: @rrbest yes you make an error. You should call `data()` as in your question and not `data`.

Comment: Yes, this works and allows me to use the data with other callers. Thanks a lot, I gave you some reputation.